# Android notepadv2 tutorial...im getting errors

Tags: android

I am trying the tutorial notepadv2 for android.  I did everything the tutorial said (and used only the code they gave me)and i am getting errors all over the place.   Help!!!!

this is my NoteEdit.java file in /src

```
package com.android.demo.notepad2;

  import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

  private EditText mTitleText;
  private EditText mBodyText;
   private Long mRowId;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);

mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

mRowId = null;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
    String body = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);
    mRowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    if (title != null) {
        mTitleText.setText(title);
    }
    if (body != null) {
        mBodyText.setText(body);
    }
}

confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, mTitleText.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY, mBodyText.getText().toString());
        if (mRowId != null) {
            bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
        }

        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

}

this is my Notepadv2.java file in /src

```
     package com.android.demo.notepad2;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Notepadv2 extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private Cursor mNotesCursor;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID,0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        createNote();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(Menu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
        fillData();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, c.getString(
            c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY, c.getString(
            c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    switch(requestCode) {
    case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
        String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
        String body = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);
        mDbHelper.createNote(title, body);
        fillData();
        break;
    case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
        Long mRowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId != null) {
            String editTitle = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
            String editBody = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, editTitle, editBody);
        }
        fillData();
        break;
    }

}
```

}

These are the two files that the errors are coming from

Comment: Hi. Please post the actual error, or we won't even know where to begin.

Comment: You should post the errors.  Are they `RuntimeException`'s or are they compile time issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoteEdit` will not compile because it has no class declaration...

```
package com.android.demo.notepad2;

  import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

//missing this line:
//public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

  private EditText mTitleText;
  private EditText mBodyText;
   private Long mRowId;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
```

Without a class declaration, the parser will spit up errors all over the place, as nothing will make sense anymore.

I am not sure if there are any errors in `Notepadv2` just by looking at it.